# Должен ли программист/разработчик напрямую общаться с заказчиком

Tags: работа

Меня мучает один вопрос: должен ли программист/разработчик общаться напрямую с клиентами/заказчиками если для этого в структуре организации предусмотрены менеджеры?
Меня иногда просят позвонить клиенту и уточнить как он видит тот или иной функционал, а мне, честно, не очень-то хочется этого делать, особенно когда приходится играть в игру "что хочет заказчик".
Может быть, в силу возраста и небольшого опыта, я чего-то не понимаю в этой жизни, поэтому прошу высказаться по существу.
P.S. Не интроверт.

Comment: в общем, для этого менеджеры и созданы - что бы решать внешние проблемы, осмысливать их и делать ТЗ.

Но иногда практикуется такой метод - когда программист работает с заказчиком напрямую. В этом есть свои плюсы.

Если Вам это не нравиться - так и скажите начальству.

Comment: На прошлой работе не давали с заказчиком общаться, только иногда перенаправляли письма. Сейчас сам с ним общаюсь, все вопросы решаем сразу. Менеджера интересует только сколько часов отработал) в принципе так как есть сейчас меня устраивает вполне. Не играем в испорченный телефон

Comment: должен ли тимлидер  общаться с кандидатами? ведь для этого существуют HR! :) система устарела, расслабьтесь  и пристегните ремни.

Comment: Должен. (...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если менеджер не может справиться, т.е. жует сопли, как выше сказали, то это плохой менеджер, **а программисту надо доплачивать за такие дела**... Если пишется под конкретного заказчика ПО, то лучше работать напрямую с заказчиками. При общении выпытывать у них все малейшие тонкости, которые приходят в голову, делать поведенческую логику ПО, и естественно все это записывать. Когда настанет момент сдачи проекта, записи могут пригодиться :)

У меня часто, при разговоре с заказчиками выходит, что заказчик не понимает своих желаний полностью, что вызывает небольшой ступор в разработке :( .

Comment: "У меня часто, при разговоре с заказчиками выходит, что заказчик не понимает своих желаний полностью, что вызывает небольшой ступор в разработке :( ."
аналогично :(

Comment: Я всегда на пользу дела общался с будущим пользователем. Иногда, даже, пренебрегая прямым запретом начальника: у нас был отдел постановки задач, и предполагалось, что это его исключительная обязанность, а программисты этого делать не имеют права. Однако, не получалось у нас с этим отделом: то они неправильно что-то воспримут от юзера, то мы их не поймем. Приходилось самим. Пользователь, конечно, большой путаник, но вопрос:"О чем ты думаешь, когда исполняешь данную технологическую операцию?",- как правило, помогал делу.

Comment: естественно, играть в испорченный телефон не очень эффективно (если промежуточное звено менеджер). Будет лучше если этот менеджер - является программистом (team лидер, технически подкован в области программирования), который способен поставить конкретную задачу разработчикам, и который представляет общую картину итогового ПО. и естественно это задание делит между программистами :)

Answer (score 8):

Общение с заказчиком - штука мерзкая. Но если умеешь - то без куска масла не останешься - фриланс всегда выручит. А вот если работаешь в конторе или сам себе содержишь менеджера\посредника для этих целей - то общение с заказчиком напрямую не только не нужно, но еще и конкретно может навредить проекту.

Answer (score 7):

Ничего зазорного в этом нет. Менеджер не всегда может понять определенные технические моменты и ему приходится жевать сопли. И начальник, чтобы не терять клиента и авторитетность поручает это разработчику.

Если разработчик этим проектом не занимается, и ему поручают обсудить с заказчиком те или инные вопрос, то соответственно разработчик не должен общаться с заказчиком.

Comment: Если менеджер жуёт сопли - то это хреновый менеджер. Так что зазорное есть, но ситуация это обыденная.

Answer (score 5):

Если Вы участвуете в разработке ТЗ или проекта, то однозначно, надо общаться. И с боссом и (это важнее всего) с людьми, которые непосредственно будут использовать Ваш продукт.

Именно в рамках такого общения возникает понимание, что именно (на деле, а не в словах ТЗ) нужно реализовать.

А вот финансовую сторону вопроса решают манагеры (собственно программистов  к внутреностям этих дел обычно не подпускают).

Comment: в последнее время менеджерами также начали называть Руководителей проектов (или team лидеров), которые представляют полную задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Мы - программисти создаем продукты, и очень часто на заказ, то есть мы должны по максимуму создать то что нам заказано, а не то что мы представили (как поняли проект). Следовательно чем теснее общение с заказчиком, тем больше вероятность того что мы произведем именно то что от нас и требовалось.

А по себе скажу что это довольно облегчает жизнь, так как не приходится гадать хотел заказчик именно этого или нет, просто спрашиваеш и реализовываеш. Идеального ТЗ нет и не может быть.

Comment: И заказчик садится Вам на шею, и процесс разработки идёт бесконечно.

Comment: да, на счет шеи актуально, кстати ) необходимо в самом начале понять основную задачу, а дальше, узнавать только ньюансы, за все доработки, повышать стоимость проекта )

Comment: На счёт шеи очень правильно подмечено, но общаться нам надо, ведь я, например, не знал как работают сетевые маркетинги, поэтому пришлось спрашивать у заказчика как это работает, а потом как ему надо чтобы это работало, жалко, что приходится всегда объяснять - нужна возможность - СКАЖИТЕ ОБ ЭТОМ, не сказали - не будет, я не экстрасенс.